# How to set variables with FOR Loop parameters in a Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, set

I need to loop through a file, affect the values to a variable, then loop into a second  file and use these previous variables:

```
for /F "delims=, tokens=1-3" %%a in (Test_1.txt) do (
    set Var1=%%b
    set Var2=%%c
    for /F "delims=, tokens=1-4" %%a in (Test_2.txt) do (
        if "%%d"=="" (
            echo %%a           !var1!            !Var2!>>Test_3.txt
        )
    )
)
```

How can I affect the first parameters to a variable?

Comment: The inner __FOR__ should not use `%%a` as loop variable like the outer __FOR__ using `%%a`, `%%b` and `%%c` for the three tokens, but for example `%%d` and so `%%d`, `%%e`, `%%f` and `%%g` for the four tokens. PS: I recommend to use upper case loop variables instead of lower case. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` to get displayed the help on several pages and read especially the section about the modifiers and you should know why the usage of `%%A` to `%%G` would be better as less confusing.

Comment: Fixing the issue is easy, but you do realise this will not match line by line right? each of the lines in file1 will be matched with each of the lines in file 2.. not line 1 matched to line 1 only..

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to read your files in parallel line by line? If so, two nested `for /F` loops are not the right choice...

Comment: No, I want to check the first line of Test_1 in all Test_2 lines.Then the second line of Test_1 in all Test_2 lines etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you then do not even need delayed expansion at all:

Each loop must have it's own unique token variables.

```
for /F "delims=, tokens=1-3" %%a in (Test_1.txt) do (
    for /F "delims=, tokens=1-4" %%d in (Test_2.txt) do (
        if "%%e"=="" (
            echo %%d           %%a           %%b >> Test_3.txt
        )
    )
)
```